# time table / datebook as in Sunbird for Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, calendar

I would like to implement a calendar in my Qt-based program as it is already implement in Mozilla Sunbird (different colors and categories are important).

Is there any "simple" possibility to realize that or do I have to create it all by myself, beginning at zero? Is there a good tutorial to create such a calendar with standards, so that I could import it in Mozilla Sunbird for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at what [KOrganizer](http://userbase.kde.org/KOrganizer) implements. You would probably have to strip some KDE-specific functionality though.

Comment: I would agree to take a look at existing program, cause writing your own calendar control is really hard.

Comment: Agreed, i should have mentioned that explicitly. KOrganizer for example is already constructed as a control for another application (Kontact).